# Magic similar to psychic abilities, including hiding the group and starting fires

Tags: story-identification, magic, psychic

I'm looking for a fantasy novel, pre-2000. It's young adult fantasy.

- Magical abilities involved talents similar to psychic abilities.
- One character could hide the group, preventing others from seeing them.
- One character could start fires.
- They were on some sort of quest and had to go into the enemy territory.

Argh! It's so frustrating. I can't remember much about the book, but would recognise it instantly.

It's not Xanth and not Julian May. It's sort of a Stephen King's *Firestarter* meets Andre Norton type novel.

Comment: In this story was the 'fire starter' character taking the other to a wizards college of sorts? And teach the other how to light a candle with his mind?

Comment: Nope, it was not that one. No college, no candles.

Answer (score 5):

Got it.
Douglas Hill: Blade of the Poisoner.

Comment: in retrospect: my memory was damn fine got all the major characters right too!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something from Mercedes Lackey's [Valdemar Universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes_Lackey_bibliography#Valdemar_universe), most likely the end of the [Arrows trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes_Lackey_bibliography#.22Arrows.22_trilogy). It could also be from the [Mage Storms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes_Lackey_bibliography#The_Mage_Storms) trilogy as well.

Comment: checked it out, nope not that either.