# Book ID: YA fantasy novel, possibly from the 80s, where main characters have special abilities

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I'm looking for the title of a YA fantasy novel I read back in the late 80s.  The main character was a young boy that gets taken in by a group of people that came together to help him and save the land.  Each of the main characters has a special ability that they have to hide from the rest of the land.  I think the boy's ability was to start fires, which he finds out later in the book.  One of the main characters had the ability to see all around him at all times, even if his eyes were closed or he was blindfolded.

Any thoughts on what it is?  I loved it as a kid and would like to track it down again.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39277/magic-similar-to-psychic-abilities-including-hiding-the-group-and-starting-fire

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124066/childrens-fantasy-blind-monk-leading-boy-who-can-control-the-elements (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 6):

The book you are looking for is Douglas Hill's [*Blade of the Poisoner*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/689341.Blade_of_the_Poisoner) (and sequel *Master of Fiends*).  The character with the 360 degree vision even while blindfolded made it easy for me to identify.

[image: Book cover]